# How to use MEF in a WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, dll, mef

The following article [questions about using MEF in a WCF service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230603/questions-about-using-mef-in-a-wcf-service) mentions in passing what I'm struggling to implement.

The problem is: I'm building a generic WCF service that has a four methods that take 2 parameters; productid (numeric) and some xml data (string). The service will load a dll dynamically based on the productid. I want MEF to do the heavy lifting for me. However, I can't seem to figure out how to wire up the MEF code.

The goal is that I once the WCF is compiled i won't have to recompile it again. I would just write another product dll and drop it in a Products folder. I'm thinking of naming the dll like ProductID_Product.dll, so i can programmatically associate the ProductID with the product and launch the correct dll based on the supplied productid.

Should I put the MEF code in the Service.svc.cs file?

Should I implement a MVC/MVVM pattern, and if so, how? Where does the bootstrapper code sit?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Just pick any introductory example about MEF. Seriously you'll need to write very little code. You don't need to do anything programmatically and your DLL may even be called A.DLL, B.DLL and so on (otherwise no point to use MEF, right?). You can put [Import] (or method you'll prefer) where you want (probably where you'll need such types). MVC/MVVM? Nothing to do with MEF.

Comment: Thanks Adriano, the problem I'm having is where do i write the MEF code in my WCF? My WCF has multiple entry points, should i create a static class that pre-loads the DLL refs when called by any method? should I just do it per method call? or am i just totally over-engineering this?

Comment: Just do it in class constructor (see [this example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648(v=vs.110).aspx)). You don't have to manage when and how that DLLs are loaded (as you don't need to worry how and where your WCF service is loaded).

Comment: Sometimes I miss the obvious. Thanks Adriano, I'll try this out and let you know how it works out.